# "Compose PSM Master Package" doesn't do anything

Tags: psm, psm-studio

I made a game for PlayStation Mobile, and I'm ready to build the master for publishing.

Per the mastering instructions, I have filled out all the required information in app.xml, created app keys for this specific application, and built on Release.

And now that I click on "Compose PSM Master Package", the PSM Studio pretty much does nothing. I have .psdp and .pspp files in the Release folder, but I don't get a .psmp file for submission.

I think all my account information is okay, including bank account information.

I also tried deleting and recreating the app keys, but "Compose PSM Master Package" still refuses to do anything.

What am I missing? What kind of interaction should I expect from "Compose PSM Master Package"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, who knows what was it. Recreating my project from scratch worked. I kept the original project, and made a deep file comparison, and apart from the created project GUID, there were no other differences between the old and new projects.

Now my game is "Waiting for Review"

Regarding the expected interacion, as soon as you click on "Compose PSM Master Package", you get a login screen so you can log into PSM. Then you get a confirmation. After one or two minutes, you get confirmation that the master package was created.

So, who knows...